# Compare properties of objects stored in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an JavaScript array of this format:

```
var dimensions = [
{dim: 590, token:'...'}, 
{dim: 800, token:'.....'}, 
{dim: 2500, token:'........'}
];
```

Data in `dimensions` array is populated dynamically i.e. I' don't know whether it is gonna be zero, one or 50 objects with `dim` and `token` properties.

What I need is to pick `token` from object that have largest value of `dim`, and smallest value of `dim`. Anyone have a clue how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dimensions = [
{dim: 590, token:'...'}, 
{dim: 800, token:'.....'}, 
{dim: 2500, token:'........'}
];

// Sort the function in ascending order and pick the first and the last element.
var minmax = dimensions.sort(function(a,b){
                  return a.dim - b.dim;
             }).filter(function(el, i){
                 return i==0 || i==dimensions.length-1;
             });

// minmax will have two values, first will be minimum and second will be the largest.
console.log("Smallest: "+minmax[0].token);
console.log("Largest: "+minmax[1].token);
```

Comment: because of the compexity of sort

Comment: its even more worst, because of filter. there is no need to filter the result of a sorted array, because of the nature of sort, the lowest is at the beginning and the highest is at the end or vice versa, depending on the sort order. so for the result is eiter element `0` and element `length-1` required. the sorting komplexity is another problem, because for just iteratin over big o is just O(N) for sorting it is, depending on the sort mechanism at least O(n*ln(n)).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It returns an object with the min and max object of the array.

```js
var dimensions = [
        { dim: 590, token: '...' },
        { dim: 800, token: '.....' },
        { dim: 2500, token: '........' }
    ],
    result = dimensions.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r.min = r.min || a;
        r.max = r.max || a;
        return { 
            min: r.min.dim < a.dim ? r.min : a, 
            max: r.max.dim > a.dim ? r.max : a
        };
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: interesting, I shall review this carefully now

Answer (score 0):

[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.) the `dimensions` array first in ascending order and then get smallest and largest `token` value

```
dimensions.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.dim) - parseInt(b.dim);
});

var smallest = dimensions[ 0 ].token;
var largest = dimensions[ dimensions.length - 1 ].token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` function to `sort` the `array` first and then pick `first` and `last` element from array.

```
dimensions.sort(function(a,b)
{
  return a.dim - b.dim
});

var tokenOfSmallest = dimensions[0].token;
var tokenOfLargest = dimensions[dimensions.length - 1].token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although most answers provided here are correct, they are not the optimal solutions for your problem (Except Nina Scholz).

Sorting the array via `Array.sort()` takes a Big-O complexity of `O(n*log(n))`, but your problem could certainly be solved with a faster, `O(n)` algorithm.

```
    var dimensions = [
      {dim: 590, token:'...'}, 
      {dim: 800, token:'.....'}, 
      {dim: 2500, token:'........'}
    ];

    function getTokenForLargestDim(array) 
    {

      if(array.length === 0) { throw new Error('Empty array'); }

      var maxDim = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
      var maxIndex = -1;

      for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var lastDim = maxDim;

          if(dimensions[i].dim > maxDim) { maxDim = dimensions[i].dim; maxIndex = i;}
      }

      return array[maxIndex].token;

    }

    getTokenForLargestDim(dimensions);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can reduce your array to find max/min:

```
var result = dimensions.reduce(function(r, item) {
    r.max = !r.max || r.max.dim < item.dim ? item : r.max;
    r.min = !r.min || r.min.dim > item.dim ? item : r.min;
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result.max.token);
console.log(result.min.token);
```

Comment: your solution returns an empty object.